# Wait for the output & then execute a command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script which gives some output. But sometimes the output takes a very long time. How it is possible to like just wait for the output command for 5 seconds, if there is no output within 5secs we execute bash-script-2. If there is output we execute bash-script-1.

I tried searching the web couldn't get anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the output to a log file, and then `tail -f` the log file with a timeout and match for anything:

```
some-long-running-command > log-file &
if timeout 5 tail -f log-file | grep .
then
  # grep found something before tail was killed
  bash-script-1
else
  # tail was killed before grep found anything
  bash-script-2
fi
```

The [`timeout` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) is from GNU coreutils.